# Joomla 4 - AJAX | com_ajax - server error 500

Tags: php, joomla

In Joomla 4 I can't get com_ajax working.
I'm using jQuery 3.6; I created a module mod_ajax and installed successfully but calls to com_ajax doesn't work, why?

// mypage.html

```
  link = "index.php?option=com_ajax&module=ajaxx&format=json&task=100" ;
  $.post(link,  function(data, status){  });
```

// mod_ajaxx.php

```
$path= JPATH_ROOT."/modules/mod_ajax/";
$opt=$_POST['option']; $uri= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$name=$_POST['task']; 
$tmp = "\n\r  opt:".$opt."\n\r  uri:".$uri ."\n\r  task:".$task;  
file_put_contents( $path.'log.txt',  $tmp)  ;
```

// log.txt

```
  opt: 
  uri:/jomkop/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=12&Itemid=126
  task:
```

Devtools return error 500 on this link, why?
https://www.example.com/jomkop/index.php?option=com_ajax&module=ajax&format=json&task=1-save_form-0-0

Where are my URL variables?
According to Joomla: "Additional variables and values used by your extension may also be included in the URL." - https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface
I tried with helper.php as well, same result.
My Joomla: 4.0.1

Thank you!

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Joomla questions should be asked on [Joomla Stack Exchange site](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you, I agree . How do I close it? (looks I can only delete it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by loading Joomla API in my php script.
Thanks

Comment: After you extend your Stack Exchange account to include Joomla Stack Exchange -- if you'd like me to facilitate the migration of this whole page to JSE, please let me know.

Comment: Can you explain your solution in more detail. I have the same problem

Comment: You need to load Joomla framework in your php script, then add a rule in .htaccess to mask the name of the script itself, so it looks like you're calling a Joomla controller. I found a working example here: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B09H1RV4XF/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_bibl_vppi_i0